# Rails route to username instead of id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to change the rails routes from /users/1 to /username. I currently set this up so it works for the actions of showing and editing. The actual issue is that when I go to update the user by using:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f|%>
```

It never updates, because the update action is routed to /users/:id. Is there any way to route this so that it works for /username? (which is the route that is rendering in my forms as the action). I've been scratching my head over this one for a while now.

EDIT:

The issue isn't routing to username, that it working correctly. The issue is that the form routes to /username for update, however the update route for users is still /users/:id instead of :/id.

I tried updating my routes to this, but to no avail:

```
match '/:id', :to => "users#show", :as => :user
match '/:id', :to => "users#update", :as => :user, :via => :put
match '/:id', :to => "users#destroy", :as => :user, :via => :delete
```

EDIT:

Doh! This fixed the issue:

```
match '/:id', :to => "users#show", :as => :user, :via => :get
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In your user model:

```
def to_param
  username
end
```

The `to_param` method on ActiveRecord objects uses, by default, just the ID of the object. By putting this code in your model, you're overwriting the ActiveRecord default, so when you link to a User, it will use the `username` for the parameter instead of `id`.

Comment: Does this affect anything else in the app or just the routes?

Answer (score 20):

In the User model override the `to_param` method to return what you want used in the URL.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    username
  end
end
```

In your controller instead of using `User.find(params[:id])` you now need to use `User.find_by_username(params[:id])`

Comment: Would it be better to specify `param: :username` in the routes file? Because the param should not be called `:id` anymore, but instead it should be called `:username`

Answer (score 5):

You can use friendly_id gem: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Comment: If you actually add the code snippets and not just a link, this would be a much better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to override `to_param` if you don't want to, you can just specify in the form  tag like this:

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => user_path(:id => @user.username) do |f|%>
```