# Show User Profile Devise Rails

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I am trying to allow users profiles to be viewed. I am using devise and have followed [Creating a `Users` show page using Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086583/creating-a-users-show-page-using-devise)

Currently has a route of '/users/1' with 1 being the id of the user. I would like to make it '/users/username'.

I tried to implement this by doing:

**"config/routes.rb"**

```
match '/users/:username',   to: 'users#show',       via: 'get'
```

**"app/controllers/users_controller.rb"**

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:username])
end
```

Even with this ^^ the route is still 'users/1'

Comment: The link Jon Friese posted provides the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FriendlyId, it is easy to use.

https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid?view=asciicast

Comment: Can this be used with devise? I am having trouble with devise and friendly_id. I would ideally like to use it within a controller but the example in the railscast has it in a model.

Comment: Yeah, it works with devise. I'm not sure about using it in the controller rather than the model, I've never done that.

Comment: I don't want it in the model, because that will mess with my devise method & my overridden devise methods - Unless you can suggest a good way to do so?

Comment: I don't know man. I can't see your code, friendly_id might not be the best solution for you. Will this work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735315/rails-route-to-username-instead-of-id? It's an easier solution anyways.