# Changing Route from "/:id/model" to "/model"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to change my path from root/carts/56 to root/cart.

I applied the logic from this question [Rails route to username instead of id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735315/rails-route-to-username-instead-of-id), which changes the id of the user to the username in the path.  That works because the username can be set to unique.

I want a /cart to lead (obviously) to the one cart the visiter (no users) is working with and get rid of the
:cart/:id.  I **DO NOT** use a user model, otherwise I would just do @user.cart (:user/cart)

So I (understandably so) get this error

```
Invalid route name, already in use: 'cart'
```

because this line

```
  match '/:carts/:id' => 'carts#show', :as =>'cart', :via => :get
```

Relevant routes:

```
                carts GET    /carts(.:format)                     carts#index
                      POST   /carts(.:format)                     carts#create
             new_cart GET    /carts/new(.:format)                 carts#new
            edit_cart GET    /carts/:id/edit(.:format)            carts#edit
                 cart GET    /carts/:id(.:format)                 carts#show
                      PATCH  /carts/:id(.:format)                 carts#update
                      PUT    /carts/:id(.:format)                 carts#update
                      DELETE /carts/:id(.:format)                 carts#destroy
```

UPDATE:

With `resource :cart, :only => :show  # note 'resource' not 'resources'`
 I get an improvement, but can I remove the id from the path somehow?

```
http://localhost:3000/cart?id=52
```

is what it gives me.

Sorry - the line that gives me the id in the URL is

```
 <li><%= link_to "Cart", cart_path(id: session[:cart_id]) %></li>
```

Is a singular resource really what I need?  I am creating the carts in a session like this

```
  <% if session[:cart_id] == nil %>
        <li><%= link_to "Cart", new_cart_path %></li>
  <% else %>
```

The idea there being if they haven't created a cart yet, they will create one when they visit the page.

I actually followed the tutorial for the carts [here](http://intertwingly.net/projects/AWDwR4/checkdepot-30/section-9.1.html)

Comment: Please post your `rake routes` output.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a singular resource. `resource :cart` rather than `resources :cart`

Comment: *What* gives you a URL with an ID parameter? What's the code that's generating cart links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routes file use

```
resource :cart, :only => :show  # note 'resource' not 'resources'
```

This will give you a cart_path that you can call.  It will hit the show method in the carts_controller.  If you need /root/ theres a few ways to add that.

Put this above the user path that's declared in the routes.rb file.

You may need some validation to ensure users don't select names that are reserved.

Comment: Since I don't have a user model is it impossible to achieve something like 'http:localhost:3000/cart'?

Comment: If you don't have a user model, you can just ignore everything about users.

Comment: When you call `cart_path`, make sure you don't include any other params.