# How to redirect a static URL to a rails resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We're migrating our site to rails, but want/need to maintain URLs from the old site, and wanted to set up a way to redirect the old URLs to the new rails routes.  The old URLs are in the following format:

```
/event/something
/event/something-else
```

Is there a way to set up a route based on `/event` that picks up the value of what follows (i.e. "something" or "something-else"), looks the value up in a DB lookup table, gets the appropriate resource id (e.g. `new_events.id`), and then redirects to the new Rails url, i.e. `/new_events/1`?

I was trying to do something like:

```
get 'event/:url_value' => 'my_controller#lookup'
```

but can't figure out how to access the value of `:url_value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're halfway there. Inside of your controller, you access the `:url_value` parameter using `params[:url_value]`.

With some assumptions about your naming conventions, your resulting method would look something like:

```
def lookup
  @event = Event.find_by old_url_value: params[:url_value]
  redirect_to event_path(@event), :status => :moved_permanently
end
```

Who likes showing IDs in the URL, though? Why don't you just preserve the URIs? Maintain that `url_value` parameter in the table, write your `show` method like this:

```
def show
  @event = Event.find_by url_value: params[:id]
end
```

And add this method to your Event model:

```
def to_param
  url_value
end
```

Your routing file would just go back to:

```
resources :events
```

See [`to_param`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Integration/to_param) for more info and this [somewhat related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735315/rails-route-to-username-instead-of-id). From the same question I linked, a good thing to use would be [some sort of slug generating gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

Comment: @dc You're welcome! I'm curious - did you end up using `to_param`?

Comment: I actually did not end up using to_param.  may be something to implement later however.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the passed new urls via params hash, and redirect to new events url:

```
#in your my_controller

def look_up
  url_value = params[:url_value]
  # look up in the db using url_value
  event = Event.find_by( name: url_value ) # this is dummy code, use you own query to look up in DB and get the related event
  # redirect
  redirect_to "/new_events/#{event.id}"
  # if you have route name like new_events_path, then you can use
  # redirect_to new_events_path(event)
end
```