# Rails - SEO friendly URLs with Self joined models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Right now there are two models: Category and Product.  Categories are self joining to make sub_categories.  Category has_many Product, who of course belongs_to Category.

The question I have is this: How Do I map the routes for these resources so that they have SEO friendly URLS.

For example: If the user clicks on the "Lamas" category, then clicks on the "Maintenence" sub-category, and then finally clicks on the "Lama Polish" Product.  The path will be:
http://lamasareawesome.com/categories/1/categories/26/products/11

What I want is:
http://lamasareawesome.com/lamas/maintenence/lama-polish

So far Im not having much luck trimming the controller name out of the path, and replacing it with a model attribute.

Comment: You may have to look at [**friendly_id**](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

Comment: [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735315/rails-route-to-username-instead-of-id) is also quite similar to yours. `friendly_id` or `to_param` would be two different ways to approach it.

Comment: thank you both for the great recommendation.  I was unaware of either of these gems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating routes which use another attribute than the ID is pretty trivial. [FriendlyID](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) a great out of box solution but it does will only get you to URLs that look like:

```
/categories/lamas/categories/maintenance/products/lama-polish
```

Creating URL's such as `lamas/maintenence/lama-polish` is definitely possible but will be difficult since its not conventional and there are many potential pitfalls.

You could for example start out with:

```
resources :categories, path: '/' do
  resources :categories,  path: '' do
    # resources :products 
  end
end
```

Which will create:

```
                Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                      Controller#Action
   category_categories GET    /:category_id(.:format)          categories#index
                       POST   /:category_id(.:format)          categories#create
 new_category_category GET    /:category_id/new(.:format)      categories#new
edit_category_category GET    /:category_id/:id/edit(.:format) categories#edit
     category_category GET    /:category_id/:id(.:format)      categories#show
                       PATCH  /:category_id/:id(.:format)      categories#update
                       PUT    /:category_id/:id(.:format)      categories#update
                       DELETE /:category_id/:id(.:format)      categories#destroy
            categories GET    /                                categories#index
                       POST   /                                categories#create
          new_category GET    /new(.:format)                   categories#new
         edit_category GET    /:id/edit(.:format)              categories#edit
              category GET    /:id(.:format)                   categories#show
                       PATCH  /:id(.:format)                   categories#update
                       PUT    /:id(.:format)                   categories#update
                       DELETE /:id(.:format)                   categories#destroy
```

**But then there is a supersized gotcha** - let's say the request is for

```
GET /lamas/joe-the-lama
```

How is Rails supposed to know that this request should be handled by `LamasController` and not `CategoriesController`? You would have to do a database query for both. Of course this is not an issue if you always have two categories but you get my drift - things are going to get complicated fast.

The standard Rails style restful routing may be a bit wordy but it does avoid a lot of potential ambiguities.

Comment: Thank you for your hard work.  I can see that you spun up a rails app just to demonstrate the routes.  I think I agree with you. after a lot of struggling I just decided to rely on bread-crumbs to try to establish some continuity.  Another issue I ran into was: what happens if the parent category has products and sub-categories.  My brain still hurts!

Comment: Thats probably a good idea, having routes like that works ok for mostly static content / blogs where the structure is somewhat fixed. But it gets really messy when you are dealing with real REST applications wher thing can be nested at different levels. 

If you want to see a real nightmare look at the Wordpress [WP_Query class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), it tries to do URL parsing, route matching and DB queries all rolled into this huge craptastic class.  WARNING: Is known to cause foul language and involuntary hurling of objects through the workplace.