# Action show to find value from hash instead of id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am still learning rails and have done a lot of readings, but I am not very clear about how params, 'show' actions work yet.

For example we have UsersController, 'index' action is showing all the users with the code `@user = User.all`, and 'show' action is looking into each users, by using the code `@user = User.find(params[:id])`

I understand that they are all from the database, where User is a model.

However in my scenario, what if the data I am showing in views, doesn't go through database, instead in the 'index' action it is something like this - 
`@user = [{name => "alex"}, {name => "peter"}, {name => "john"}]`

and in my 'show' action, how can I write the code so that it finds the users by name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Rails app, the data that you show in your views, do not necessarily have to come from/through the database. You can always show any data you want in your views.

For example, in your `index` action, if you have this:

```
@users = [{name => "alex"}, {name => "peter"}, {name => "john"}]
```

Then, in your `index` view, you can show only those users by looping through the `@users` instance variable.

Same for `show` page as well.

If you want to show the users by name in your `show` page, you have to set the users by name in an instance variable e.g. `@users_by_name`:

```
@users_by_name = User.find_by(name: user_name)
# or you can hard code the values if you want like index action
```

and then this `@users_by_name` instance variable will be available in your `show` view so that you can loop through that and show the user names.

Originally, the `show` page is designed for showing a particular user related information, but you can show whatever information you want going against the conventions.

To be able to have a route like this: `localhost:3000/users/alex` that will show the user `alex`'s information, you can add a route in your `routes.rb` file:

```
get 'users/:name', to: "users#show"
```

And, in your controller's `show` action, something like this:

```
 def show
   @user = User.find(params[:name])
 end
```

Then, show the `@user` information in your view page.

P.S. This is not a good idea to find user by name as there might be more than one user with same name in the database and it will create conflict/ or give wrong data in such situations.

Comment: Thanks. What if my hash structure is something like this `[{name => "alex", age=> 17, location => "Canada"}, {name => "peter", age=> 20, location => "Australia"}`, Is there a method to write in the controller so that if I look for localhost:3000/users/alex, and it will show the page for alex, where my view I can just write "<%= @users_by_name.age %> to get the age for alex?

Comment: You can follow this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735315/rails-route-to-username-instead-of-id
to achieve that goal I believe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My original question is that if it is possible for 'show' action not to go through database?

Comment: This is a great explanation

Comment: @pyfl88 I think I answered that in my answer. Yes, it is possible for `show` action not to go through database. Let me know if you have any other question.

Answer (score 2):

In show action , we search the user specific record not all.

So , we have to provide some unique identifiers as parameters to find the specific record.

For eg.  Your view should be similar to the params we are passing as below:

```
<% @user.each do |user| %><br>
  <%= link_to user.name, user_show_path+"?name="+user.name %><br>
<% end %><br>
```

In show action , write the code

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by(:name => params[:name])
end
```

Also in routes.rb , write the below code:

```
get 'users/:name', to: "users#show"
```

For the above solution, make sure that name field will be unique.

Answer (score 0):

> My original question is that if it is possible for 'show' action not to go through database

Sure.

Your show action can be the following if you wanted it to:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @user = "me"
   end
end
```

You really don't have to do anything specific in your application, Rails is just a framework and has certain conventions if you want it to work efficiently.

What you're asking is if you can populate your `@user` object from a third party set of data...

... *Yes you can* ...

The way to do it would be in the *model*, not the controller:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   # populates from Hash
end
```

You'd then be able to populate the data in the controller from the model again:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @user = User.__________ #-> pull from your hash
   end
end
```

---

> finds the users by name

That's simple - just pass the `name` through the url: `url.com/users/marine_lorphelin`

This will set the `:id` parameter to `marine_lorphelin`, with which you'll be able to look up the name through your model:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @user = User._______
   end
end
```

If you were using a database with your user model, you'd be able to use the following:

```
def show
   @user = User.find_by name: params[:id]
end
```

Since you're not, you'll have to attach your XML hash to your model somehow. This, I don't know without specifics such as where you're getting your data from, how you're accessing it, and which routes you're going to send to invoke it.